# Facebook login review failed - "crashes upon opening"

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I tried my first Facebook Login Review submission. Facebook responded by saying

1) Your app downloads successfully, but crashes upon opening. Please resolve any technical issues that prevent us from testing your app.

2) If this is an iPad app, please resubmit under the iPad platform. I tried installing it on the iPhone Simulator as well but the app crashes. Thank you for your time.

Question:

1) The app did not crash on my end. I have tested the .app file by running this command:

```
ios-sim launch APPNAME.app --family ipad
```

I can see the app runs on my iPad simulator. What could be the reasons that crashed the reviewer's simulator?

2) What does Facebook means by "please resubmit under the iPad platform"? If I look at the settings page of the Facebook app, it is clearly under "iOS platform" and there is no way I can specify that I want "iPad platform".

Answer (score 0):

When my app launches, it calls some Multipeer Connectivity API to discover other devices in the vicinity.

Once I disabled this feature, Facebook reviewer does not complain about app crashed anymore.